# WordPress Address (URL) and Site Address (URL)

Tags: php, wordpress, url

The values in WordPress Address (URL) and Site Address (URL) are grayed out.  I have looked in wp-config.php but there is nothing set there - I tried to hard code preferred address in this location it did not change the site address.

```
define( 'WP_HOME', 'https://...' );
define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'https://...' );
```

I went to functions.php and tried to set it there -  did not change;

```
update_option( 'siteurl', 'https://...' );
update_option( 'home', 'https://...' );
```

Lastly I went into the database and tried to change it there, edited the wp__options file and tried to change - it did not change:
[image]

Is there anywhere else I can edit to get this to change or stop it from being grayed out so I can change from settings > general in the admin panel?  Where could this be hiding?

[image]

This is grayed out section - cut off to hide my url

Thank you

Comment: What do you mean "grayed out"? Can you provide some screenshots?

Comment: I assume by grayed out you mean in the options editor. According to the [source for that page](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/270f2011f8ec7265c3f4ddce39c77ef5b496ed1c/wp-admin/options-general.php#L78 ), if those constants are set, the fields are disabled. If you are trying to change your sites address, I strongly recommend using the CLI https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/search-replace/

Comment: i updated and added picture

Comment: I dont have access to CLI, have to go through the service provider who is a pain

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried manually adding these to your `wp-config.php` file?
They are not included in the `wp-config.php` file by default.

```
define( 'WP_HOME', 'http://yoursite.com' );
define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'http://yoursite.com' );
```

Comment: first thing i tried it is in the question.